# it says that there is no matching member function to call for 'insert'. This is for a school project, and I really am stuck

Tags: c++

So where it says "num.insert" is where the problem is. I have no clue how to fix this. This is for a school project, so I need the answers soon. Please be nice. Also, please try not to change my code so much.

```
int strToDecimal(int baseChosen, string num);
string decimalToBase(int num, int baseChosen);

int main(void)
{
  int menu;
  int baseChosen;
  int numberDecimal;
  string number;

  cout << " Hello! This program was created and perfected by Jacob Griffin. ";
  cout << " Please choose a base to convert into." << endl;

  cout << "1. Hex" << endl;
  cout << "2. Octal" << endl;
  cout << "3. Binary" << endl;
  cout << "4. Decimal" << endl;
  cin >> menu;

  switch(menu)
    {
      case 1:
      {
        baseChosen = 16;
        break;
      }
      case 2:
      {
        baseChosen = 8;
        break;
      }
      case 3:
      {
        baseChosen = 2;
        break;
      }
      case 4:
      {
        baseChosen = 10;
        break;
      }
      default:
      {
        baseChosen = 0;
        cout << "You cannot chose this."<<endl;
        break;
      }
    }
    cout << "Enter a number to convert: ";
    cin >> numberDecimal;
    //convert string to decimal
    cout << "Decimal: " << numberDecimal << endl;
    cout << "Binary: " << decimalToBase(numberDecimal, 2) << endl;
    cout << "Octal: " << decimalToBase(numberDecimal, 8) << endl;
    cout << "Hex: " << decimalToBase(numberDecimal, 16) << endl;
}

int strToDecimal(int baseChosen, string num)
{
  int sum;
  for(int i=0; i<num.length(); ++i)
  {
    switch(sum)
    {
      case 'A':
      {
        num.insert(0,10);
        break;
      }
      case 'B':
      {
        num.insert(0,11);
        break;
      }
      case 'C':
      {
        num.insert(0,12);
        break;
      }
      case 'D':
      {
        num.insert(0,13);
        break;
      }
      case 'E':
      {
        num.insert(0,14);
        break;
      }
      case 'F':
      {
        num.insert(0,15);
        break;
      }
      default:
      {
        sum=sum+(num[i]-48)*pow(baseChosen,num.length()-1-i);
        break;
      }
     }
   }
  return sum;
}

string decimalToBase(int number, int base)
{
  string result;
  int remainder;
  int num = number;
  while(num > 0)
  {
    //cout << "loop";
    remainder = num%base;
    switch(remainder)
    {
      case 10:
      {
        result.insert(0,"A");
        break;
      }
      case 11:
      {
        result.insert(0,"B");
        break;
      }
      case 12:
      {
        result.insert(0,"C");
        break;
      }
      case 13:
      {
        result.insert(0,"D");
        break;
      }
      case 14:
      {
        result.insert(0,"E");
        break;
      }
      case 15:
      {
        result.insert(0,"F");
        break;
      }
      default:
      {
        result.insert(0,string(1, remainder + 48));
        break;
      }
    }
  num /= base;
  }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: You can fix that compiler error by inserting a string like “10” instead of a number like 10 into your string.

Comment: The compile-time problem may be trying to shove an `int` in a `std::string`, but the *real* problem is that you're doing it in the first place. I literally makes no sense to modify `num` in the context of that function, when what you should be doing appears somewhat to be only in your `default` case, and even that I question. Related to that, building `sum` as you are invokes *undefined behavior* because you never gave `sum` an initial value. Therefore, `sum = sum + ...` is adding something to something completely unknown. Best of luck, though.

Comment: Thank you WhozCraig, but I still don't know how to fix it. Could you show me what to do? I am a beginner.